# Extract the numbers in a dataframe of strings based on one criteria in Python

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, extract

I want to extract all the numbers before the symbols `->`. For now I only have this:

```
df['New'] = df['Companies'].str.findall(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)').str[-1]
```

which only extracts the numbers before the last `->`

I modified it slightly to this:

```
df['New'] = df['Companies'].str.findall(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')
```

but I didn't get what I wanted, instead I want something similar like this:

```
       Companies                                        New   New2   New3
0   -> Company A 100->Company B 60->Company C 80->...   100   60     80
1   -> Company A 100->Company B 53.1->Company C 82...   100   53.1   82
2   -> Company A 100->Company B 23-> Company D          100   23
3   -> Company 1 100->Company B 30-> Company D          100   30
```

Note that the `New's` can be more than 3 columns depending of how many `->` there are in the strings. Also, some of the `Company` names have integers in their names, which I do not want to include in the new columns.

Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) with catch integer or `float`s before `->`:

```
pat = r'(\d*\.\d+|\d+\.?)->'
df = df.join(df['Companies'].str.extractall(pat)[0].unstack().add_prefix('New'))

print (df)
                                           Companies New0  New1 New2
0   -> Company A 100->Company B 60->Company C 80->    100    60   80
1   -> Company A 100->Company B 53.1->Company C 82    100  53.1  NaN
2   -> Company A 100->Company B 23-> Company D   ...  100    23  NaN
3         -> Company 1 100->Company B 30-> Company D  100    30  NaN
```

If need floats:

```
df = df.join(df['Companies'].str.extractall(pat)[0].astype(float).unstack().add_prefix('New'))
print (df)
                                           Companies   New0  New1  New2
0   -> Company A 100->Company B 60->Company C 80->    100.0  60.0  80.0
1   -> Company A 100->Company B 53.1->Company C 82    100.0  53.1   NaN
2   -> Company A 100->Company B 23-> Company D   ...  100.0  23.0   NaN
3         -> Company 1 100->Company B 30-> Company D  100.0  30.0   NaN
```